# How to use Settings.Global class in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to use the Settings.Global class which is introduced in Android 4.2.

I am using the following code:

```
Log.d("Global.Setting", getGlobalSettingValues(Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS))
private String getGlobalSettingValues(String key){
        return Settings.Global.getString(mcontex.getContentResolver(), key);
    }
```

expected Output:

> AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS=cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax.

But it shows following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   /**
     * @return A comma separated list of radios that need to be disabled when airplane mode is on
     */
    private String getGlobalSettingValues() {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor globalCursor = null;
        String aeroplaneMode = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            globalCursor = cr.query(Settings.Global.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if(globalCursor != null && globalCursor.moveToFirst()){
                aeroplaneMode =  Settings.Global.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS);
            }
        } 
        if (globalCursor != null) {
            globalCursor.close();
        }
        return aeroplaneMode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See if [This Link](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=2826) gives you a pointer.

Code extract from the above link for quick reference:

```
private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
    if (apiVersion < 17) {
       return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
    } else {
       return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
    }
}
```

Follow the link for a detailed explanation on how to do it.

Comment: No.it didn't work. For example when i use following code:  Log.d("Global.Setting",Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS) ..It can provide following output:airplane_mode_radios....But i want the following output:   AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS=cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax.

Comment: My question is that i want to extract the value of Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS                                            using Settings.Global.getString(mcontex.getContentResolver(), key)        method